# MySQL trigger without restart?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to add a MySQL trigger without restarting the whole server?

Comment: Of course. A new trigger is active immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See the manual section on [`CREATE TRIGGER` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to. It's just like views, procedures, you can start using it once it's created.

Meanwhile if you changed your MySQL setting by editing the configuration file, then you need to restart MySQL for it to take effect.